# VBA code to copy value next to searched value

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA coding I want to copy cells in same row for the value that I had searched.

I am getting an error when i tired to access. for Example I want to find "abcd" in my xl sheet.
Let say that "abcd" is found in cell c12, I want to copy values in cells E12, F12.

I am getting error I am trying to use offset property.

```
Private Sub FindingValues()
    Dim val As Variant
    val = InputBox(" Please Enter the value you want to search for")
    Set c = Cells.Find(val, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstaddress = c.Address
    Do
    MsgBox "Value of val is found at " & c.Address
    Set c = Cells.FindNext(c)
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstaddress
    End If

End Sub
```

In the above code I am able to get the address of the cells I had searched for. I want to find the values next to row cell values. 
like let us say "abcd" is found in cell c12, I want to values in d12, e12..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Sub FindingValues()
    Dim val As Variant
    val = InputBox(" Please Enter the value you want to search for")
    Set c = Cells.Find(val, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = c.Address
        Do
            MsgBox "Value of val is found at " & c.Address & vbCrLf & c.Offset(0, 1).Value & vbCrLf & c.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Set c = Cells.FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always work with `option explicit` as this produces helpful error information.

Second, you should try to avoid using `Variant`, if you know the type. There *are* exceptions to this rule, however. But for simple programs, it a good rule to stick to.

On your code - you could use the `offset` function. The first argument offsets rows, and the second argument offsets columns.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FindingValues()
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstaddress As String

    val = InputBox(" Please Enter the value you want to search for")
    Set c = Cells.Find(val, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstaddress = c.Address
    Do
    MsgBox "Value of val is found at " & c.Address
    MsgBox "Value found at +1 column offset is " & c.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Set c = Cells.FindNext(c)
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstaddress
    End If

End
```